# Substituir espaço por nova linha com powershell

Tags: cmd, powershell

Como é possível rodar um arquivo .bat que execute o powershell para substituir espaços por nova linha?

Atualmente tenho este cenário no arquivo run.bat:

```
set id=1
powershell "(gc %id%_01.txt) -replace '[a-zA-Z]','' | Out-File -encoding ASCII %id%_01.txt"
```

E este conteúdo no arquivo 1_01.txt

```
Nome Qualquer
15000 qualquer 14999
```

O resultado desejado é

```
15000

14999
```

Tentei modificar o comando com base em alguns exemplos que vi.

```
powershell "(gc %id%_01.txt) -replace '[a-zA-Z]','' -replace ' ','`r`n' | Out-File -encoding ASCII %id%_01.txt"
```

Mas a saída fica errada:

```
`r`n
15000`r`n`r`n14999
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conforme consta [neste comentário](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39104275/replace-a-character-with-new-line#comment65555850_39104275), as aspas simples consideram o texto de forma literal, para fazer o que você quer, utilize aspas duplas:

```
set id=1
powershell "(gc %id%_01.txt) -replace '[a-zA-Z]','' -replace ' ',"""`r`n""" | Out-File -encoding ASCII %id%_01.txt"
```

Você pode evitar quebras de linhas desnecessárias no começo do arquivo desta maneira:

```
set id=1
powershell "(gc %id%_01.txt | Select-Object -Skip 1) -replace '[a-zA-Z]','' -replace ' ',"""`r`n""" | Out-File -encoding ASCII %id%_01.txt"
```

Referência para [Select-Object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34357022/4322614).

Comment: obrigado, também deu certo desta forma -replace ' ',\"`r`n\"